# deleting a column in a table javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a JavaScript application using Google Visualization API. I wrote a event listener so whenever the user clicks in the column, he has the option to hide it, if he does not want to see it.

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select',
            function selectHandler(){
                var data_table = table.getDataTable();
                confirm("hide column?", "Yes", "No");
                alert(data_table.removeColumn(0));

            }
    );
```

I get the following error:

```
data_table.removeColumn is not a function    
alert(data_table.removeColumn(0));
```

The API description can be seen [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_removeColumn). It's interesting why the first alert tells me "30", the number of columns in the table, while the `removeColumn(index)` function does not do anything at all. Any Thoughts? 
Thanks

Comment: Do you need to support rows/cells that cross colspans? What about rows that have a colspan `<td>` in them before your column? What about rows that has a rowspan `<td>` lengthening them?

Comment: @Phrogz I don't need to support rows/cells that cross colspans. I also updated my question, so please take a look

Comment: @Phrogz Could you make your comment an Answer, so I could accept it? you were right on the money!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that perhaps `data_table` is not, in fact, not the type of object you expect.
Have you used `console.dir` to look at the methods available on it?

Answer (score 2):

Is it because your code snippet invokes `removeColum` instead of `removeColumn`?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're saying that the second two alerts don't happen.

If so, it's probably because of this typo...

```
  // -----------------------v
alert(data_table.removeColum(1)); // missing "n"
```